# How can I not send a cookie when I use the Cache-Control header in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, session, cookies, catalyst

I'm using sessions in my Catalyst app via `Session`, `Session::Store::DBIC`, and `Session::State::Cookie`.

I have a few controllers and methods that send out data with a `Cache-Control: public` header, so its essential that the `Set-Cookie:` header *not* go out with those responses (otherwise, it'd be cached and sent to other clients, leading to possible security issues). I haven't found a good way to accomplish this.

How can I tell `Session` or `Session::State::Cookie` to not send a cookie in response to a given request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a little RTFS, `Session.pm` overrides Catalyst's `finalize_headers`
method and sets the cookie there, through a rather deep call chain:

```
finalize_header
⇒ _save_session_expires
⇒ session_expires
⇒ _extended_session_expires
⇒ extend_session_id (…::Session::State::Cookie)
⇒ update_session_cookie (…::Session::State::Cookie)
```

There does not appear to be any way to flag anything in the chain to
stop. The only check is a method in `Cookie.pm` called
`cookie_is_rejecting` which just compares the configured cookie path to
the request path.

So, it looks like the best way to do this is to add my own override to
either `update_session_cookie` or `cookie_is_rejecting`. I think I'll
use `cookie_is_rejecting`.

Here is the code I finally used. Note that this is rather klugy, but it works...

```
package Catalyst::Plugin::Session::State::Cookie::Sanity;
use base qw/Catalyst::Plugin::Session::State::Cookie/;

use MRO::Compat;

use strict;

sub cookie_is_rejecting {
    my ($c, $cookie) = @_;

    ($c->stash->{cache_control_time} // 0) > 0
        or $c->maybe::next::method( $c, $cookie );
}

1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit unusual to approach it this way but I think I get what you are doing.

If I recall correctly, the Cookie State module simply sets the cookie in the response object:

```
$c->response->cookies
```

I don't think there's any magic there, and it only sets it to create or extend the session time. If you want to ensure that no cookies are sent.  Clear out `$c->response->cookies` in Root end and you should be good to go.

JayK

Comment: If there is a better/more usual way to approach this, I'd love to hear it. This is my first real Catalyst app, so I may well be doing things in silly manners for no good reason.

Comment: `$c->log->debug("Cookies are: " . pp($c->response->cookies));` in my root's end logs cookies as being an empty hash already, and yet Set-Cookie is being sent anyway.

Comment: [info] *** Request 9 (1.125/s) [10894] [Mon Jul 27 11:20:48 2009] ***
[debug] "GET" request for "js/tools/e3f84575109c4612819ae19e28973135" from "172.16.1.241"
[debug] Path is "js"
[debug] Arguments are "tools/e3f84575109c4612819ae19e28973135"
[debug] Found sessionid "f356a9509668ea25f70b6b8dd2edef318dad95a1" in cookie
[debug] Restored session "f356a9509668ea25f70b6b8dd2edef318dad95a1"
[debug] Cookies are: {}
[debug] Rendering template "js/tools.js"
[debug] Passing page through as text: js/tools.js
[info] Request took 0.110160s (9.078/s)